# spring boot fat jar register to eureka with a weird port

Tags: java, netflix-eureka

I encountered a weird problem with spring cloud. I run a spring cloud project defined server port as 8888 in eclipse as run as java application, and register this project to the remote eureka server, it's working fine. but when I package the project and run as java -jar, will register to eureka server with 8080 port, so other service access this service will get a connection refused error.

Comment: Are you using an application.properties or application.yml file? If so, please post here

Comment: yes, using application.properties

Comment: spring boot version is 1.5.2 and spring cloud version is Dalston

Comment: I changed the log level to DEBUG and found the port field and instanceid field has different value in the register info. why?

Comment: I meant, actually post the contents of your application.properties file

Comment: thanks for your answer. it has been fixed, caused by a bug in springfox-swagger2 2.6.0 , upgrade to 2.7.0 to fix this issue. swagger bug NO. is 1514